# Knockout JS + Update helper text

Tags: knockout.js

I am fairly new to Knockout JS. I am trying to do a simple task, if the drop down menu changes show a helper text depending on the value selected in the drop down list.

My example is located on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dnfCb/10/

Note: I am not sure if linking to jsFiddle is allowed, if not I will paste the code here. It seems the ko.computed event only fires on load. Can't seem to get it to fire when the criteria changes.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your `<select>` value to an actual observable property to see changes.

```
<-- ------------------------ here....................... -->
<select name="search_option" data-bind="value: criteria">
    <option value="O">Order Search</option>
    <option value="P">PO Number Search</option>
</select>
```

and

```
var orderSearchViewModel = {
   criteria: ko.observable("O")   // give a default value
};

orderSearchViewModel.helperText = ko.computed(function() {
    if (this.criteria() == "P") {
        return "Searching by PO Number";
    }else {
        return "Searching by Order Number";
    }
}, orderSearchViewModel);

ko.applyBindings(orderSearchViewModel);​
```

Note that `criteria` is a function that needs to executed in order to get the underlying value, so

```
if (this.criteria == "P")
```

would not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/dnfCb/11/

---

BTW, I think the the self-contained view model set-up is a little nicer:

```
function OrderSearchViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  this.criteria = ko.observable("O");
  this.helperText = ko.computed(function() {
    if ( self.criteria() == "P" ) {
      return "Searching by PO Number";
    } else {
      return "Searching by Order Number";
    }
  });
}

ko.applyBindings( new OrderSearchViewModel() );​
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as well. I noticed the line var self = this. Why did you do this? why not just reference criteria() instead of self.criteria() ?

Comment: @Gordon Because there is no `criteria` in scope, as far as the function that calculates the value is concerned. It would work if `criteria` was declared with `var`, but that's not the case. (Hint: when the calculating function runs, `this` points to the `window` object.) Declaring `var self = this;` is a common technique to store a reference to "the parent object". The other variant would be to pass `this` as the second parameter to `ko.computed()`, like you did in your code.